# Cmake finds hdf5 but tries to link against dll on windows

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I use `find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX REQUIRED)` in my CMAKE script to load the include directories and libraries of HDF5. Cmake tells me

```
Found HDF5: C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.0/bin/hdf5_cpp.dll (found version "1.10.0") found components:  CXX
```

And generates my `visual studio` solution.
I also use the library stored in `${HDF5_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES}` for my target, but when I try to build it, I get a Linker Error `LNK1107` saying that for file `hdf5_cpp.dll`:

```
invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x380
```

which I think is due to the fact that `visual studio` is trying to directly link against the `dll` file instead of against the `lib` file which is in another folder, namely in:

```
C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.0\lib
```

**Question:** Is this a bug in FindHDF or did I configure something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used hdf5 on windows for some time, but I do recall there being a bug that causes it to link against the dll instead of the lib.
you should manually set (either via the command line cmake -D method, or via the cmake gui)

    `HDF5_hdf5_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\libhdf5.lib
    HDF5_hdf5_cpp_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\libhdf5_cpp.lib`

etc. - or just 

    `HDF5_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\libhdf5.lib
    HDF5_cpp_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\libhdf5_cpp.lib`

depending on whether you have an older or newer version of FindHDF5 (they change the library var names in newer versions - check the ones used to make sure you get them right - I'm doing this from memory so might have made a mistake)

EDIT:
If the option of manaully specifying the libs is a problem, then there is the option of using FindPackage(HDF5 NO_MODULE) if your hdf5 library was compiled using cmake generated makefilesetc. 
When using NO_MODULE, the find package scripts will bypass the findhdf5.cmake script and look for the HDF5Config.cmake or hdf5-config.cmake file that is placed in the relevant subdir of the hdf5 build/install folfer.

This is cross platform friendly and is supported by all newer hdf5 versions - provided they were built using cmake and not ./configure ...

Comment: Hm, this is not a good option, as this cmake script is supposed to run on different platforms, and I would like to avoid writing lots of if cases with platform specific stuff. I wonder why this isn't fixed, if this is a known bug.

Comment: Here is the issue, for those that want to follow it and see if it ever is resolved: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16534

Comment: And for the manual specification of the paths, one should probably use quotation marks due to the spaces in the paths.